# What is the origin of the word 鬻?

Tags: etymology, word, idioms

The word 鬻 (yù) appears to originate as a joint pictogram from:

- 粥 depicting the rice and two whirls of steam on the sides
- 鬲 (pronounced lì?) a cooking vessel

Later 粥 alone came in use to express the original meaning (congee), and 鬻 became a loan for "to sell". The loan is reported in the Zhuangzi 庄子.

However I've always known that the actual meaning of this word is "to sell poetry for a living", which is basically the translation of the idiom 鬻文为生. This idiom is also the only sentence where I ever heard the character 鬻 (heard, yes, I actually heard someone uttering this). The dictionaries I checked report only 卖 as a synonym, and other usages consistent with "selling", but the offered examples all gravitate toward "selling art" as 鬻画, 鬻哥 where it looks like a separable verb.

Given the highly specific collocations, I wonder if there is a story behind the etymology of the word, e.g. the same way there is a story behind a chengyu like 画蛇添足。I couldn't find any so far.

Comment: The more famous idiom is [賣官鬻爵](https://www.chinesewords.org/idiom/show-7569.html), meaning "sell government officer positions and noble titles" (a form of corruption). You can find countless examples in history and this idiom might even usable in modern days

Comment: Archaic characters like 鬻 are no longer used alone in modern Chinese, 鬻's only usage is being a part of some idiom, much like 黷(wantonly engage in) has no role in modern Chinese besides being a part of the idiom [窮兵黷武](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/175239).

Comment: Have you consulted [漢典](http://www.zdic.net)? It contains many more examples.

Comment: 鬻 is a phonetic loan for , if you want to trace the word etymology look at uses of  instead. The glyph origin doesn’t have anything to do with *sell*; it is strictly only relevant to *congee* (and the description given on most sites looks backwards, 粥 appeared before 鬻).

Comment: @dROOOze my computer doesn't display the character. Do you have a unicode code point, picture or something else?

Comment: U+27E07 https://www.zdic.net/hant/%F0%A7%B8%87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better refer to these links:
https://www.zhihu.com/question/20010669/answer/26173785

https://www.zhihu.com/question/22107477/answer/20311667

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%AC%BB#Etymology

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A7%B6%A0#Chinese

1. The word {congee} was first denoted by [image: ⿱(⿲弓毓弓)鬲] (here 毓 denotes its pronunciation and 䰜 stands for cooking utensils) and later the character developed into 鬻(**鬻≠粥+鬲，鬻=米+䰜**). Finally it was simplified to 粥.
2. Both 粥 and 鬻 could be used to denote the word {sell}. As dROOOze pointed out,
   this use is nothing but a phonetic loan for .  stills exists as a phonetic complement in many characters like 續贖讀櫝 (its glyph form becomes resembling 賣mài but they are etymologically unrelated).

As the history developed the usage of 鬻 to mean {sell} was fixed and 粥 became only used to mean {congee}.

3. The use of 鬻 to mean {sell} is seen as traditional Chinese today and hence only appears in idiomatic uses.

Examples in ancient Chinese:

楚人有鬻楯與矛者。 There was a person in *Chu* state who was **selling** shields and lances.

我世世為洴澼絖，不過數金；今一朝而鬻技百金，請與之。We have been bleaching cocoon-silk for generations, and have only gained a little money. Now in one morning (=at once, immediately) we can **sell** [to this man] our art (the way to make a salve which kept the hands from getting chapped) for a hundred ounces - let me give (sell the art) to him(=let him have it).